# Is there reason why the ghost in yellow jacket has to be aggressive towards Josh?

Tags: plot-explanation, insidious-red-door

In the movie, ***Insidious The Red Door***, when Josh practices a game of matching photos in order to improve his mind-fogness, which is caused by loss of memory from previous Insidious movie; he is attacked by a ghost wearing a yellow jacket.

- This ghost in yellow jacket breaks through Josh's windows, chases after him, bangs on his door, and pushes him into a closet and knocks him out.

A small box of photos is discovered by Josh in the process and this ghost turns out to be his late father.

What confuses me is:

- Josh's father shows up by the end of the movie, appearing to be kind and caring, leaving Josh a lamp so that Josh can return to his physical body from the spirit world.

There seems to be very little point for Josh's father to be aggressive during his first appearance; all his father's intention is to lead Josh to recover his memory and discover the small box of photos.

Why would he need to be so aggressive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my point of view, Josh's dad appearing as a scary ghost in the movie made it really thrilling, like in any scary movies. As the story went on, we saw that this wasn't just random. It was a big part of the story.

This scary ghost meeting was super important because it got things moving in the story. It helped Josh find some old photos, which helped him remember things from his past. It was all part of a plan to lead Josh to the truth.

This scary encounter built suspense, made the story move forward, and showed us why the characters were doing what they were doing.

In horror movies, a good scare is just the start of a bigger, more interesting story. This movie is a horror movie, so it's all about giving you chills and thrills.

Comment: "This scary ghost meeting was super important because it got things moving in the story. *It helped Josh find some old photos*, which helped him remember things from his past." The question still stands. Why should've Josh's father's ghost been so aggressive so that Josh can find the old photos? Couldn't he find them if the ghost kindly directed him to them? So, I don't think the aggressiveness helped Josh to recover those photos.

Comment: What if the ghost's aggressiveness was just in Josh's point of view (i.e. he delusioned about the existing ghost's attitudes). What if other people who are able to see the ghosts see that as a kind ghost at the same time?